# Acceder a variables de session en servidor desde react?

Tags: php, reactjs

estoy usando react y la verdad soy muy nuevo en esto, el caso es que desde una función ajax llamo a un archivo del servidor y creo una  variable de session, después desde otro archivo intento llamar a esa variable de session también mediante ajax a php y me la da vacía.

Me voy intentar explicar mejor.
1- Una funcion ajax llama a un archivo "A" que general una session x
2- Otra función ajax llama a un archivo "B" para tomar el valor de sessión x pero el resultado es que no accedo.

Si desde el navegador entro directamente a los archivos, si  me crea la variable y despues desde el otro accedo a ella. Imagino que tendrá que ver con el servidor virtual que te crea react.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery'; //Importro la librería Jquery ya instalada
class Login extends Component {

sacarToken() {
      var parametros = {
        "usuario": "P",
        "clave": "P"
      }
      $.ajax({
        data: parametros,  
        url: 'https://pr/react/login.php',
          type: "POST",
          success: function(data) {
                console.log(data); 

            },
      });

   }

  render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.sacarToken.bind(this)} >Generar Token</button>

    )
  }
}

export default Login;
```

login.php

```
<?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["token"]="hola";
    echo $_SESSION["token"];
 ?>
```

AL pulsar en generar token el console.log fuciona y genero la variable session en el servidor.

Segundo archivo de react

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery'; 
class Header extends Component {

  pVolcado() {
   $.ajax({
    url: 'https://pr/react/pVolcado.php',
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
              console.log(data); 
            },
    });

 }

  render() {
    return (

      <div id="volcados" className="col-xs-6  col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">


          <button onClick={this.pVolcado.bind(this)} >Generar Volcado</button>

        </div>


    );
  }
}
export default Header;
```

El archivo pVolcado.php donde intento recuperar el valor de la variable session

```
<?php //Este archivo pinta los defectos de una partida
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    session_start();
echo $_SESSION["token"]; //Me lo pone en blanco

?>
```

Comment: No muestras código y la pregunta es muy amplia. Además seguramente el problema esté en el código del servidor por el manejo de la sesión o en la llamada AJAX que no manda el identificador de sesión, y ambas cosas no tienen nada que ver con React

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Pablo, he intentado rectificar antes de que me cierren la pregunta, este es el código. Lo que me resulta raro es que accediendo directamente a la ruta del archivo php del servidor me funciona bien, 1 Crea la sesión y después accedo a ella, pero llamando desde ajax si crea la sessión pero después me la pone en blanco.